# Zend Framework Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\InvalidFieldNameException

Tags: php, symfony, zend-framework, doctrine-orm

I have this issue since I have moved my website to an other server. The configuration is the same, any hint?

File:

```
/var/www/page/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/AbstractMySQLDriver.php:71
```

Message:

```
An exception occurred while executing 'SELECT s0_.id AS id_0, s0_.answer AS answer_1, s0_.users_usrId AS users_usrId_2, s0_.question AS question_3 FROM secret_answer s0_ WHERE s0_.users_usrId = ?' with params [83440]:
```

SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 's0_.users_usrId' in 'field list'

Stack Trace:

```
#0 /var/www/page/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/DBALException.php(128): Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\AbstractMySQLDriver->convertException('An exception oc...', Object(Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOException))
#1 /var/www/page/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Connection.php(855): Doctrine\DBAL\DBALException::driverExceptionDuringQuery(Object(Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOMySql\Driver), Object(Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOException), 'SELECT s0_.id A...', Array)
#2 /var/www/page/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query/Exec/SingleSelectExecutor.php(50): Doctrine\DBAL\Connection->executeQuery('SELECT s0_.id A...', Array, Array, NULL)
#3 /var/www/page/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query.php(321): Doctrine\ORM\Query\Exec\SingleSelectExecutor->execute(Object(Doctrine\DBAL\Connection), Array, Array)
#4 /var/www/page/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/AbstractQuery.php(969): Doctrine\ORM\Query->_doExecute()
#5 /var/www/page/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/AbstractQuery.php(924): Doctrine\ORM\AbstractQuery->executeIgnoreQueryCache(NULL, NULL)
#6 /var/www/page/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/AbstractQuery.php(766): Doctrine\ORM\AbstractQuery->execute(NULL, NULL)
#7 /var/www/page/vendor/custom/p-server-core/src/PServerCore/Entity/Repository/SecretAnswer.php(23): Doctrine\ORM\AbstractQuery->getOneOrNullResult()
#8 /var/www/page/vendor/custom/p-server-core/src/PServerCore/Form/Password.php(85): PServerCore\Entity\Repository\SecretAnswer->getAnswer4UserId(83440)
#9 /var/www/page/vendor/custom/p-server-core/src/PServerCore/Controller/AuthController.php(188): PServerCore\Form\Password->addSecretQuestion(Object(DoctrineORMModule\Proxy\__CG__\PServerCore\Entity\User))
#10 /var/www/page/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/Controller/AbstractActionController.php(78): PServerCore\Controller\AuthController->pwLostConfirmAction()
#11 /var/www/page/vendor/zendframework/zend-eventmanager/src/EventManager.php(322): Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController->onDispatch(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#12 /var/www/page/vendor/zendframework/zend-eventmanager/src/EventManager.php(179): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
#13 /var/www/page/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/Controller/AbstractController.php(105): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerEventUntil(Object(Closure), Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#14 /var/www/page/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/DispatchListener.php(119): Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractController->dispatch(Object(Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Request), Object(Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Response))
#15 /var/www/page/vendor/zendframework/zend-eventmanager/src/EventManager.php(322): Zend\Mvc\DispatchListener->onDispatch(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#16 /var/www/page/vendor/zendframework/zend-eventmanager/src/EventManager.php(179): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
#17 /var/www/page/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/Application.php(332): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerEventUntil(Object(Closure), Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#18 /var/www/page/public/index.php(18): Zend\Mvc\Application->run()
#19 {main}
```

Thanks and kind regards.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the field is missing. You might have to update your database schema or adjust the orm-configuration for the entity.

Assuming you use annotations, you can specify the table name in the [@Table](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html#annref-table) and the field name to the [@Column](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html#annref-column) annotation. To make sure the entity maps to the right table and the property to the right field.

Comment: Hello, the table was working properly already on my old backend, simply on the current one it does not.

Comment: Well, the error tells me it's looking for a field `users_usrId` in your table `secret_answer` that is not there. Either your schema changed, your mapping is wrong. If both schema and model are configured correctly, I'd probably investigate the query in `PServerCore\Entity\Repository\SecretAnswer::getAnswer4UserId` as that seems to be the place where the query throwing the error is being assembled and submitted.

Comment: I will look at it. I will udate you asap. Thanks again. :)